# How to 'attach' metadata to a bitcoin receive address

Tags: transactions, hash, encryption, contracts

I need to generate a receive address that is directly associated with some metadata, M, that forms part of a verifiable contract.

I require that customers can verify that an address really was generated from a specific contract message, but I do not want them to have the private key to the address.

I obviously don't want to bloat the blockchain nor do I wish to use non-standard transactions. P2SH is also not possible as it is still largely unsupported by many online wallet providers.

So here is my first attempt, based on (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=108423.0) ...

```
# generate an EC key pair for the company
issuer_public_key = issuer_private_key * G

# create a contract message string, M
M = 'Terms of contract bla bla and also includes issuer_public_key for safety'

# generate a hash of the message
e = SHA256(M)

# create an EC point that is known to both parties
contract_point =  (e * issuer_public_key)

# generate a public key for this contract to form our receive address. Customer agrees to contract when they send BTC to receive address.
receive_public_key = contract_point + issuer_public_key

# the private key for the receive address is thus
receive_private_key = contract_point + issuer_private_key
```

Feedback much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

That's all well and nice, but it turns out that courts aren't interested in "mathematical proofs" (with good reason).  I recommend reading all the books by Bruce Schneider.

Let's say you got someone to pay you at `receive_public_key`. Does that mean he has agreed to contract `M`? No.

The courts would still need to see documentation that your partner actually saw and agreed to the contract `M`. You could have emailed the guy and said "I'll give you $10 if you send Bitcoins to `receive_public_key`, then later claim that he agreed to contract `M`.

This same thing happened in the 90's, with vendors claiming cryptographic digital signatures had the property of [Non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation). But the courts disagreed. For example, someone can hold a gun to your head and make you 'sign' a contract (digital or otherwise). No court will consider that a valid contract, fancy math or no fancy math.

Comment: this is an uninformative answer. a complete waste of time and space.